# Why `std:variant`'s `operator=(T&& t)`'s noexcept spec doesn't depend on inner types's destructor's noexcept spec?

Tags: c++, variant, nothrow, std-variant

Long title: Why `std:variant`'s `operator=(T&& t)`'s noexcept specification doesn't depend on inner types's destructor's noexcept specification?

I can see on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/operator%3D) that

```
template <class T> variant& operator=(T&& t) noexcept(/* see below */);
```

is

```
noexcept(std::is_nothrow_assignable_v<T_j&, T> && 
std::is_nothrow_constructible_v<T_j, T>)
```

So this compiles:

```
struct FooThrow {
  ~FooThrow() noexcept(false) {throw;} 
};
static_assert(std::is_nothrow_assignable_v<std::variant<FooThrow, int>, int>);
```

But it calls `FooThrow`'s destructor which is `noexcept(false)`:

```
std::variant<FooThrow, int> x;
x = 3; // throws
```

It doesn't seem right. Am I missing something?

Comment: "But it calls FooThrow's destructor" where?

Comment: You can't check at compile time which type is being used and which type is being assigned to.  So the only option would be to not allow assignment if any type has a throwing destructor, which wouldn't be nice.

Comment: How else would it destroy the existing value guys? Remember the selected type may change

Comment: I've added a simple example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, standard library types do not take kindly to types that have throwing destructors. Or specifically, when a destructor actually emits an exception. There's a general rule about it ( [[res.on.functions]](http://eel.is/c++draft/res.on.functions) )

> In certain cases (replacement functions, handler functions, operations on types used to instantiate standard library template components), the C ++ standard library depends on components supplied by a C ++ program. If these components do not meet their requirements, this International Standard places no requirements on the implementation.
>
> In particular, the effects are undefined in the following cases:
>
> ...
>
> - if any replacement function or handler function or destructor operation exits via an exception, unless specifically allowed in the applicable Required behavior: paragraph.

Since `variant::operator=` has no special statement about throwing destructors, having those destructors actually throw is UB.